# Why is it possible to pass method reference instead of converter instance?

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have a question as to the resolved types of method::lambdas in Java 8.

Given this example method, which converts a list of objects using a given spring-core Converter implementation:

```
public static <S, T> List<T> convertToList(Collection<? extends S> input, Converter<S, T> converter) {
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<>(input != null ? input.size() : 0);
    if (input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
        for (S element : input) {
            results.add(converter.convert(element));
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then say I have a particular implementation, BoatConverter:

```
public class BoatConverter implements Converter<Boat, BoatConverted> {

    @Override
    public BoatConverted convert(Boat boat) {
       // ...
    }

}
```

One way of calling this is:

```
ConversionHelper.convertToList(response.getBoats(), boatConverter)
```

However, I note that the Java compiler (and expected results) are equally happy with this:

```
ConversionHelper.convertToList(response.getBoats(), boatConverter::convert)
```

Given convert() in this case returns a BoatConverted, but convertToList() is expecting a Converter type, my question is how the compiler resolves this apparent clash, especially since you pass in a lambda of convert() but the convertToList() utility method wants to call that method on an expected converter object passed in?

Comment: `Converter` is a functional interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Converter` is effectively a functional interface because it contains only a Single Abstract Method:

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;

public interface Converter<S, T> {
    T convert(S var1);
}
```

Which means that it can be used as a target for lambda expressions and your example could be rewritten as:

```
c -> boatConverter.convert(c)
```

In this case, your lambda is simply delegating the job to already existing instance of `Converter` and since the method signature matches the interface method, it's possible to replace it with a method reference.

The main difference is that when you are passing `boatConverter`, you are simply reusing this instance as a `Converter` but if you write `boatConverter::convert` or `c -> boatConverter.convert(c)`
 you are creating a new `Converter` instance that delegates the conversion to `boatConverter`

Answer (score 2):

Basically that converter is actually the same thing as `Function` (transforms from one type to another) and it is a `@FunctionalInterface` - since it has a single abstract method.

That's why the compiler can resolve that perfectly fine. Consider this simpler example (IMO):

```
static class ToUpperCase implements Function<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
    }

}

private static List<String> transformList(List<String> input, Function<String, String> f) {
    return input.stream().map(f).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

These both calls would work:

```
transformList(list, func);
transformList(list, func::apply);
```

But also the second could be written much more clear:

```
transformList(list, String::toUpperCase);
```

As such your example could be made more clear:

```
ConversionHelper.convertToList(response.getBoats(), Boat::getYourField)
```

`getYourField` should obviously be replaced with whatever you are doing. I find this much more verbose as it makes a clear statement that you are *transforming from Boat to some of it's fields*.